# how to extract signature from images converted into pdfs

Tags: imagemagick, tesseract, imagemagick-convert, pdftotext, python-tesseract

I have bunch of PDF files which are converted from images. I need to extract text and hand written signature from it. I am able to extract text by using Imagemagik and Tesseract ,but not able to extract hand written signature. 
kindly let me know if there is any way to extract hand written signatures from these documents.

Comment: `pdfimages` from the Poppler package maybe?